# can't get ssh running on docker via dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, docker

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4

RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server \
    && useradd --create-home --base-dir /home myuser \
    && echo "myuser:myuser" | chpasswd \
    && service ssh start
```

When I try to run this container by doing `docker run -v "`pwd`:/opt/src" -w "/opt/src" "namespace/name" php test.php` port 22 isn't open. Same thing if I try to run it by doing `docker exec -it ... bash`.

Any ideas what I need to do to get SSH running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a RUN directive are executed when the image is created, not when the container is run (they are typically used for install/setup). If you want to run something when the container is created, put it in a script that you specify with an ENTRYPOINT directive.